# imcrop matlab does not return right size

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-figure

I want to use imcrop to crop images in matlab. But, sometimes it results the images which has one size more than what I want. Basically, my question is same as this.
http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/answers/46737-how-do-i-make-the-imcrop-function-accurate-to-the-pixel
 But, even this is not solved. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

`imcrop` does return the "right size", i.e. the size specified in its documentation. A rectangle `r1 = [20 20 40 30]` is *always* not sometimes 21 by 11 pixels wide.

If your expectation of what the right size should be is different, you could index the rectangle differently. If you want a rectangle with pixel (20,20) as its upper left edge and 20 pixels tall and 10 pixels wide, you can specify `r1 = [20, 20, 39, 29]`.

`imcrop` works like this because it operates on image data consisting of pixels. Pixels are being indexed, not points in space. Mathematically, a point has no width and no height, but a pixel has the width and height of one pixel.

To provide an extreme example, `r2 = [5, 6, 8, 9]` includes the pixels from row 5 to 6 and column 8 to 9, and is thus 2 by 2 pixels wide.

Comment: If you look into the imcrop.m, this is quoted there as well.

Comment: It says "Because RECT is specified in terms of spatial coordinates, the WIDTH and HEIGHT of RECT do not always correspond exactly with the size of the output image. For example, suppose RECT is [20 20 40 30], using the default spatial coordinate system. The upper left corner of the specified rectangle is the center of the pixel (20,20) and the lower right corner is the center of the pixel (50,60). The resulting output image is 31-by-41, not 30-by-40, because the output image includes all pixels in the input that are completely or partially enclosed by the rectangle."

Answer (score 2):

I could not really resolve the problem. But, I applied a simple work around. I used imcrop to crop with the desired sizes. And then resize the cropped image to desired size again.